# "I wouldn’t say no" VS "I wouldn’t mind (it)"

Tags: idioms, expressions

For me the two expressions **"I wouldn't say no"** and **"I wouldn’t mind(it)"** (where "it" as an optional pronoun can be omitted) mean more or less the same thing and most of the time can be swapped freely without being mistake semantically. Am I right?

**Example#1:**

> **Person #1)** Do you want a coffee? 
> **Person #2)** ......... 
> **a)** I wouldn’t say no. 
> **b)** I wouldn’t mind (it).

**Example #2:**

> **Person #1)** Shall we go running? 
> **Person #2)** .........., but I need a jogging suit and a pair of running sneakers. 
> **a)** I wouldn’t say no. 
> **b)** I wouldn’t mind (it).

Comment: Yes, with **most of the time** underlined.

Comment: I'd consider the tone these are said in could change their meaning **significantly**. they're somewhat ambiguous, I wouldn't mind it leans a little more negatively and I wouldn't say no more positively, but the tone and situation is a much bigger qualifier.